# iOS background and images seem to not scale properly for retina display

Tags: iphone, ios, background, textures

When using the following code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture1.png"]];
```

The texture background of my view gets set just fine. But I can see that the images are not scaled properly for a retina display, they seem more pixelated, rather than rich in texture and color as they should be. I have had this issue with other images too, when trying to make an image the size of the iphone 5 screen fade away, only a part of it would be seen, and the rest would be cut off, even though the resolution is fine. Any idea what I am missing here?

EDIT: Does it have to do with the default dpi of the images that I am using?

EDIT #2: Here is a screenshot:
[image]

On a side note, does anyone know if good background texture sources besides http://subtlepatterns.com/?

EDIT #3: Here is a good example of me attempting to use the ios-linen pattern
[image]

Comment: can you add some screen shot?

Comment: I assume you are making double width and height @2x versions of your art? (I hate to ask)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. I am not specifying anything in my code for the images to be 2x. However I am using higher res images that would be the 2x qualification. For example, for another application's view, I have an image that is 640x1136, but unless i put it in an UIImageView, it always comes up the wrong size, and not scaled down properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firstly remove .png from image name if you are use @2x image

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture1"]];
```

Please check the image height and width for retain display ..

[By Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1) `On devices with high-resolution screens, the imageNamed:, imageWithContentsOfFile:, and initWithContentsOfFile: methods automatically looks for a version of the requested image with the @2x modifier in its name. If it finds one, it loads that image instead. If you do not provide a high-resolution version of a given image, the image object still loads a standard-resolution image (if one exists) and scales it during drawing.`

Comment: Thanks, this was part of my issue. I had to get rid of the .png and also include a -568h@2x file as well. Then, when testing on my iphone 5 the image was displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `initWithPatternImage` you should add a `UIImageView` to the `UIView` . This is better because :-

1. The `UIImageView` will contain the image according to its specific width and height.
2. Also, the `initWithPatternImage` method consumes **MORE MEMORY** than the `UIImageView`.

I would **prefer** to use a `UIImageView` rather than the

```
initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture1.png"]
```

If the image is still not clear you can add the **@2x image** to the `UIImageView` and you will see the clarity is more.